# If $f(x) = \log_ax$, show that $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \log_a(1+\frac{h}{x})^{1/h}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

If $f(x) = \log_ax$, show that
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \log_a\left(1+\frac{h}{x}\right)^{1/h},$$
 where $h\neq0$.

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$ to format your mathematics. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: I don't even know how to begin.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**
$$\Large{a^{\log_a(b)}=b\qquad\qquad a^{b/c}=(a^b)^{1/c}}\qquad\qquad a^{b-c}=\frac{a^b}{a^c}$$